# How to insert data that contain single or double quotes to database in python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, web-scraping

I have a program in python and I want to insert data into a table(using insert into statement). I receive data from web(web scraping) and the data contain both single and double quotes. As you know MySQL allows to insert both single and double quotes to a table so the error is not from database. Problem appears when I use that data in python and an error appears.
No matters if i use single or double quotes in the string (insert into statement values) in python, in both ways error appears because of the data(that contain single or double quotes).I use MySQL and Connector/python and in my script I import mysql. I hope you got this, sorry about bad English.

Comment: What are you currently doing to escape the characters? In Python you can use the backslash to escape certain characters in a string, or you can alternate quotes (use single quotes around a String that contains double quotes and vice versa).

Comment: Python database connection  packages usually provide a way to automatically escape variables (the [paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) attribute).  You should use this rather than manually escaping strings.  If you can tell us which database and connection package you are using we can advise how to do it.

Comment: Your english is fine. Don't apologize for it. If you are concatenating web data into string queries you are susceptible to SQL injection. Tell us which database and connection package you are using we can advise how to do it.

Comment: For the first comment: I didn't notice backslash thank you and as I wrote it down, script returns an error because of that data (the data has both single and double quotes) ; For the second comment: I use MySQL and I don't know actually what you mean by connection package but i installed Connector/python and in my python scripts I import mysql

Answer (score 0):

Most likely explanation for the behavior is a SQL Injection vulnerability. (That's just a guess because we are speculating about code we haven't seen; only a description of the behavior.)

The short answer is to use *prepared statements* with *bind placeholders*

https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/

If for some reason that is not possible, then at a bare minimum, any potentially unsafe values included in SQL text must be properly escaped to make them safe for inclusion

(The single quote in Little Bobby Tables https://xkcd.com/327/ is not escaped.)

As example, this SQL will throw an error, because the second single quote ends the string literal, and what follows the end of the string literal "`s wrong`" is gibberish in terms of SQL:

```
INSERT INTO mytab (mycol) VALUES ( 'It's wrong' )  
                                      ^
```

But this will work:

```
INSERT INTO mytab (mycol) VALUES ( 'It''ll work' )  
                                      ^^
```

Because the single quote within the string literal is escaped, by preceding it with another single quote.

---

The OWASP project provides a good overview of SQL Injection.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

---